# Any morphism $f: Spec B\to Spec A$ would naturally induce a locally ringed morphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

By the proof of Hartshrone's proposition 2.3, it seems to any morphism $f:Spec B\to Spec A$, it would naturally induce a locally ringed morphism $(f,f^{\#}):(Spec B,\mathcal{O}_{Spec B})\to (Spec A,\mathcal{O}_{Spec A})$.

I just imitated the proof from hartshorne part(b) to get the result, and it seems it makes sense to me, but I am not sure it I made mistakes. 
[image]

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that the whole point of this locally ringed space business is to get an equivalence of categories $\textit{commutative rings}^\circ \simeq \textit{affine schemes}$, and in particular a natural bijection $\mathrm{Hom}_{\textit{c.ring}}(A,B) \cong \mathrm{Hom}_{\textit{aff.sch.}}(\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} B,\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} A)$. Just as a topological space, Spec carries little information---any field gives you a point, any DVR gives the "Sierpinski space", etc. If you consider all continuous maps between spectra, you get too many morphisms...

Comment: E.g. you always have the obvious continuous morphism $\mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} A \to \mathop{\mathrm{Spec}} k$ for *any* field $k$ and *any* ring $A$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

If $A=\mathbb{C}$, $B=\mathbb{R}$, then $\operatorname{Spec} A$ and $\operatorname{Spec} B$ are both one-point spaces, so there is a continuous map $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$.

But there is no morphism $A\to B$, and therefore no morphism $\operatorname{Spec} B \to \operatorname{Spec} A$ of locally ringed spaces.